# Deriving BIP32/BIP44 addresses for LTC to match Jaxx

Tags: bitcoinj, litecoin

I'm using https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib to derive LTC wallet addresses from a private key so I can track transactions of the Jaxx LTC wallet.

The first few addresses generated match what Jaxx has (first 9 to be precise), but other addresses don't match.

I have compared the results with https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ and the are consistent.

The derivation path that I was using is `m/44'/2'/0'/0`.

I have also tested BTC addresses, and only first 5 addresses matched.

So the questions are:

1. Why addresses become different after some correct?
2. How can I get consistent matching with Jaxx addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research a came across this post https://www.reddit.com/r/jaxx/comments/7ix6mu/hd_derivation_bug/ which had the answer to my problem. The issue was that by using `m/44'/2'/0'/0` i was creating *external* addresses only (those that are for sending funds to). I should also create *internal* addresses (used for keeping transaction change) by using `m/44'/2'/0'/1` (note  `1` in the last position). More info this parameter here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#change